# Javascript tabbed search box tab highlighing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a search box with JavaScript and CSS tabs on it which control the destination of the search. However, when you click one tab and then another tab, the previous tab still stays selected. Is there any way to make my code have the previous tab to be deselected? I have posted a copy of my code below.

My JavaScript:

```
var isDOM = (document.getElementById ? true : false);
function getElement(id){
 if (isDOM) { return document.getElementById(id); }
}

function pageSheetClick(pageSheet){
    if ( pageSheet && pageSheet.id ){
        mode=0;
        pageSheet.className = 'bookmarkCenterSel';
        selectedPageSheet = pageSheet;
    }
}

function CheckKey(e){
if( typeof( e.keyCode ) == 'number' ) {
e = e.keyCode;
}
if (e == 13){
changePage(getElement('q').value);
}
}

function changePage(findtext){
 var tmp=findtext;
  if (mode==0) {
  pId = selectedPageSheet.id.split('_');
  if (pId[0]=='web')
      html="/search/"+tmp+"/1/";
  if (pId[0]=='images')
      html="/images/"+tmp+"/1/";
  if (pId[0]=='videos')
      html="/videos/"+tmp+"/1/";
  if (pId[0]=='news')
      html="/news/"+tmp+"/1/";
  if (pId[0]=='twitter')
      html="/twitter/"+tmp+"/1/";
  } if (tmp!="")
  window.location=html;
}
```

And then my HTML and CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.bookmarkCenterSel{
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
}
</style>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td id="web_center" class="bookmarkCenter" onclick="pageSheetClick(this);"><a href="javascript:void(null);">Web</a></td>
<td id="images_center" class="bookmarkCenter" onclick="pageSheetClick(this);"><a href="javascript:void(null);">Images</a></td>
<td id="videos_center" class="bookmarkCenter" onclick="pageSheetClick(this);"><a href="javascript:void(null);">Videos</a></td>
<td id="news_center" class="bookmarkCenter" onclick="pageSheetClick(this);"><a href="javascript:void(null);">News</a></td>
<td id="twitter_center" class="bookmarkCenter" onclick="pageSheetClick(this);"><a href="javascript:void(null);">Twitter</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="q" name="q" onkeypress="CheckKey(event);return true;">
```

To recap, my problem is that when one tab is selected and then a different one is selected, the first selected tab remains selected.

I hope you can understand what I am trying to describe.
Thanks in advance, Callum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this should work:

```
var lastTab;

function pageSheetClick(pageSheet){
    if(pageSheet && pageSheet.id){
        mode = 0;
        pageSheet.className = 'bookmarkCenterSel';
        selectedPageSheet = pageSheet;

        if(lastTab != null) lastTab.className = "";
        lastTab = pageSheet;
    }
}
```